# Trouble with Golang Application with Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, go, pipeline, azure-aks

We are develop our first Golang API Application. When whe Azure pipelines is executed for release this app the AKS pod is not created and we get this error message:

*Error: release golang-app failed, and has been uninstalled due to atomic being set: timed out waiting for the condition*

The second step is execute the command: kubectl -n xxxxx get events --sort-by='{.lastTimestamp}' and we get this message:

Failed to pull image "serverdev.azurecr.io/xxxx.golang-app.go-ver:86895": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "serverdev.azurecr.io/xxxx.golang-app.go-ver:86895": failed to resolve reference "serverdev.azurecr.io/xxxx.golang-app.go-ver:86895": failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "serverdev.azurecr.io/xxxx.golang-app.go-ver:86895": failed to resolve reference "serverdev.azurecr.io/xxxx.golang-app.go-ver:86895": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized]

The hilarius situacion, is when we develop a Net Core application, because the pod is created correctly and no get any errors.

Please, i need some advice to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

PS: We have Azure Kubernetes Service version 1.25.6 and Helm 3.7

We change many parameters in the Azure pipelines, but we get the same error, by another hand the net core app no get any error message.

Comment: do you have git submodules in your project?

Comment: Yes, we have some submodules.

Comment: let me know if my answer solves your problem

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue while deploying our go project.

***Why this error occurs?***

Consider the following folder structure:

```
my_project
 /api
 /config
 /migrations
 /submodule_1
 /submodule_2
```

In the code, we import packages this way:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/lib/pq"
    ...
    "gitlab.com/my_project/submodule_1"
    "gitlab.com/my_project/submodule_2/models" 
    ...
)
```

When our CI/CD pipeline runs and build stage comes it needs to have access to all the packages that are used in the project.

Since git submodules are considered as third party packages build process tries to fetch them.

For example `"github.com/lib/pq"` pakage is accessible with no issues since it is a public repository. But `"gitlab.com/my_project/submodule_1"` may not be accessible from the computer that is building the project thus causing this error (because of missing permissions or the repository being private)

***Solution***

You can solve this issue in two ways:

1. Make sure `build` stage has access to your submodules
2. Copy all the code within your submodules into a non-submodule folder.

We went with the second option:

```
my_project
 /api
 /config
 /migrations
 /modules/
     /submodule_1
     /submodule_2
 /submodule_1
 /submodule_2
```

In this way all the code within `modules` folder becomes part of `my_project`'s code. So `build` stage does not need to fetch it

P.S: you can use this script to copy all submodules into your new folder:

```
// Makefile
submodule-gen:
    rm -rf modules/${SUBMODULE_1_FOLDERNAME}
    rm -rf modules/${SUBMODULE_2_FOLDERNAME}
    mkdir -p modules/${SUBMODULE_1_FOLDERNAME}
    mkdir -p modules/${SUBMODULE_2_FOLDERNAME}
    rsync -r --exclude '.git' ${SUBMODULE_1_FOLDERNAME}/ modules/${SUBMODULE_1_FOLDERNAME}
    rsync -r --exclude '.git' ${SUBMODULE_2_FOLDERNAME}/ modules/${SUBMODULE_2_FOLDERNAME}
```